Standard error of the AR(1) correlation parameter in glmmTMB
Using AR(1) model in glmmTMB, with code based on the vignette (btw, haven't found any other reference documentation, that would precisely define the ar1() functionality and the corresponding summary output etc.; is there something else than this vignette?):
library(glmmTMB)

n <- 25                                              ## Number of time points
x <- MASS::mvrnorm(mu = rep(0,n),
             Sigma = 0.7 ^ as.matrix(dist(1:n)) )    ## Simulate the process using the MASS package

times <- factor(1:n, levels=1:n)
head(levels(times))

group <- factor(rep(1,n))
dat0 <- data.frame(x, times, group)

g2 <- glmmTMB(x ~ ar1(times + 0 | group), data=dat0) 
# the AR(1) correlation should be ~ 0.7 for large enough samples

summary(g2)

# compare with the raw correlation coefficient:
cor.test(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))

It seems to be fine, but I can't seem to figure out how do I get the standard error of the Corr parameter? (The AR(1) correlation)? I suppose all the optimized parameters should always have the standard error available... without any need to use some bootstrapping etc...
PS: I tried things like confint(g2) or confint(g2, parm = "theta_") but it seems to return something else...
PS: In the end, I rather need the CI. The standard error was just means to get it :-)
EDIT: Ben's current hack/solution doesn't work in general, when I add more random effects:
n <- 10                                              ## Number of time points
time.reff <- rnorm(rep(0,n), 0, 0.2)
x <- MASS::mvrnorm(1000, mu = time.reff,
             Sigma = .7 ^ as.matrix(dist(1:n)) )    ## Simulate the process using the MASS package

library(reshape2)

d <- melt(x)
d$time <- factor(d$Var2)
d$group <- d$Var1

g3 <- glmmTMB(value ~ (1|time) + ar1(time + 0 | group), data = d)

Now, when trying to extract it from the glmmTMB object, it all has just similar confusing names:
vcov(g3, full = TRUE)
#                          (Intercept) disp~(Intercept)  theta_1|time.1 theta_time+0|group.1 theta_time+0|group.2
# (Intercept)           0.0044675603195  0.0000006258999 -0.000037166774      0.0000001358308      0.0000003024984
# disp~(Intercept)      0.0000006258999  0.0763324452714  0.000014868716     -0.0014493749352      0.0063889358336
# theta_1|time.1       -0.0000371667736  0.0000148687157  0.051209915518      0.0000014854011      0.0000051939167
# theta_time+0|group.1  0.0000001358308 -0.0014493749352  0.000001485401      0.0001635499153      0.0000657916127
# theta_time+0|group.2  0.0000003024984  0.0063889358336  0.000005193917      0.0000657916127      0.0009709511260


In the vignette you reference, you'll see at the end of the section "Demonstration on Simulated Data", that internally the AR1 parameter is reparameterized: phi = theta2/sqrt(1 + theta2^2).  The theta2 parameter has an SE that you can find with g2$sdr (the second theta row in the output).

@DaveArmstrong thanks, that could be it! But is there some more official, clean way than accessing $sdr directly? I tried confint(g2, parm = "theta_") but it returns something else...

I edited the answer to include an extractor function for the theta parameterization and phi as well.  If you're looking for something "official" in the package, I don't think it's there.  The function in my answer would make it more convenient though.

I didn't see anything in my quick perusal of the glmmTMB help file.  However, it would be easy enough to make something clean that would do that.
Data
library(glmmTMB)
set.seed(519)
  n <- 25                                              ## Number of time points
x <- MASS::mvrnorm(mu = rep(0,n),
                   Sigma = .7 ^ as.matrix(dist(1:n)) )    ## Simulate the process using the MASS package

times <- factor(1:n, levels=1:n)
head(levels(times))
#> [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"

group <- factor(rep(1,n))
dat0 <- data.frame(x, times, group)

Model
g2 <- glmmTMB(x ~ ar1(times + 0 | group), data=dat0)

Extract AR parameter
Here's a function called get_AR() that will pull the AR parameter out in its theta form.  It creates a normal theory CI on theta and then does an end-point transformation to get the CI on phi the transformation of theta into the AR parameter.
theta2phi <- function (theta) theta/sqrt(1+theta^2) # AR1 link function, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html

get_AR <- function(x){
    pars <- x$sdr$par.fixed
    sds <- sqrt(diag(x$sdr$cov.fixed))
    ind <- grep("theta", names(pars))
    t2 <- pars[ind[2]]
    s2 <- sds[ind[2]]
    list(
        est = theta2phi(unname(t2)),
        ci = theta2phi(qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), t2, s2))
    )
}
get_AR(g2)
# $est
# [1] 0.6632351 
#
# $ci
# [1] 0.1793698 0.8465077 

Compare the result above with the model output below to confirm that the transformation to phi was successful. The AR1 parameter (Corr) in the summary below is the same (approx 0.66).
summary(g2)
#>  Family: gaussian  ( identity )
#> Formula:          x ~ ar1(times + 0 | group)
#> Data: dat0
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>     68.7     73.6    -30.4     60.7       21 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>  Groups   Name   Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr      
#>  group    times1 1.158e+00 1.076e+00 0.66 (ar1)
#>  Residual        1.191e-09 3.451e-05           
#> Number of obs: 25, groups:  group, 1
#> 
#> Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 1.19e-09 
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)  0.06542    0.45390   0.144    0.885

Created on 2024-12-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you very much! I polished the code a bit, this is the version I will use. Hope you don't mind :-) I am still aware though, that this is not a good clean robust solution, to directly access the $sdr... more like a dirty hack. Hope that the glmmTMB team will do something about this.

Unfortunatelly I found out that this doesn't work in general :-( Sometimes when I have other random effects there it's ind[3] so it is not reliable :-(

Here's a version that's slightly less hacky, using only well-defined accessor methods (the only special knowledge required is the name/index of the correlation parameter):
theta2phi <- function (theta) theta/sqrt(1+theta^2) # AR1 link function, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html

get_AR <- function(x, level = 0.95){
    clevs <- c((1-level)/2, (1+level)/2)
    theta <- getME(x, "theta")
    vv <- vcov(x, full = TRUE)
    cpos <- which(colnames(vv) == "theta_times+0|group.2")
    s2 <- sqrt(vv[cpos, cpos])
    t2 <- theta[2]
    list(
        est = theta2phi(t2),
        ci = theta2phi(qnorm(clevs, t2, s2))
    )
}
## $est
## [1] 0.4822741
## $ci
## [1] -0.7625872  0.9157828

On the other hand, the profile confidence intervals (which are a little slow to compute but not nearly as slow as bootstrapping) are quite different, suggesting that the Wald approximation isn't very good here:
pp <- TMB::tmbprofile(g2$obj, trace = FALSE, name = 4)
theta2phi(confint(pp))
##             lower     upper
## theta -0.09506679 0.9971448

We can illustrate the badness by seeing that the likelihood profile is far from (log)quadratic:
plot(pp)


The slow, gold-standard parametric bootstrap CIs are different still:
bb <- lme4::bootMer(g2, FUN = function(x) getME(x, "theta")[2], nsim = 500, seed = 101, .progress = "txt")
confint(theta2phi(bb))
##           2.5 %    97.5 %
## [1,] -0.6057465 0.8421749

## exclude a few weird/extreme fits
hist(bb$t[bb$t>-800], breaks = 100, freq = FALSE, 
  xlab = "Cor parameter (unconstrained scale)", main = "")


No guarantees that this is all exactly correct ...

PS I should really redo this with the same seed (519) that @DaveArmstrong used ...

Hello Ben, thanks! I was hoping for something general, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work now as I added other random effects. Suddenly it is theta[3] instead of theta[2] and also the name "theta_times+0|group.2"  is there duplicated with different number at the end and so it is hard to guess which is which. Isn't there something even more general in glmmTMB? :-)
